# URI formats are not supported in webclient c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf-rest, webclient

I call my service as you can see like this :

```
  public ReceptionView ReceptionViewByReceptionId(string receptionId)
    {
        ClientRequest.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        ClientRequest.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string result = ClientRequest.DownloadString("http://localhost:1111" + " /ReceptionService.svc/ReceptionViewByReceptionId/" + receptionId);

        var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return javascriptserializer.Deserialize<ReceptionView>(result);
    }
```

But i get this error in `DownloadString`:

```
{"URI formats are not supported."}
```

my service works ok and when i call my service by browser like this :

```
http://localhost:1111/ReceptionService.svc/ReceptionViewByReceptionId/1
```

I get the expected result .but in my application i can't

My service interface

```
 [WebGet( UriTemplate = "/ReceptionViewByReceptionId/{receptionId}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

    ReceptionView ReceptionViewByReceptionId(string receptionId);
```

As a note my function worked before without any error ,but today suddenly returns this error.

My fiddler result in browser:
[image]

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to learn something.  Use the sniffer with you browser and connect to your service and look at the format of the message.  It is not just the URL and string.  There are other header info that must be included.

Comment: @jdweng i traced it in fiddler but the service url never called why ?

Comment: The results is 200 which is DONE so the connection completed successfully.  It is possible the cookie expired or running with your application that didn't complete installed a bad cookie.  Usually when I'm debugging these issues I recommend after changing code to delete cookies from the IE browser so previous bad results don't lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the space here `" /Reception` as you can see in the url

```
string result = ClientRequest.DownloadString("http://localhost:1111" + " /ReceptionService.svc/ReceptionViewByReceptionId/" + receptionId);
```

I removed that and every thing worked fine .